# While watching a football game on TV, what does "1st & 10" mean?

Tags: rules, american-football, media

One thing that made me curious while watching a football game on TV was the numbers that appear on the ground. For instance, there's a "1st & 10" beside one team, but there was a "3rd & 6" a few minutes prior (and I think it was beside the other team). What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"1st" is the [down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_(gridiron_football)). In crude terms, a "down" is when a [play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_from_scrimmage) occurs. A play takes place when a team attempts to advance the ball from its current spot.

"10" is the number of yards needed to obtain a new series of downs (thus, "restarting" at 1st down).

In a possible scenario based on your question: On 3rd (down) and 6 (yards), Team A may have gained 7 yards (*re: the first point under Rule 7, Section 3, Article 1 - see below*). Thus, Team A is beyond the number of yards needed to obtain a new series of downs. As a result, Team A has 1st (down) and 10 (yards).

---

As a starting point, [Rule 3, Section 9, Article 5](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2016-nfl-rulebook/#article-5.-first-down) of the 2016 NFL Rulebook defines a first down:

> The initial down in each series is the First
>   Down. If it is a charged down, subsequent charged downs are numbered
>   consecutively (i.e., second down, third down, or fourth down) until a
>   new series is declared for either team.

How is a new series declared? [Rule 7, Section 3, Articles 1 and 2](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2016-nfl-rulebook/#article-1.-new-series-for-team-a) describe how for both teams.

> **ARTICLE 1. NEW SERIES FOR TEAM A**
>
> A new series of four scrimmage downs
>   is awarded to Team A when the following conditions exist:
>
> - During a given series, the ball is declared dead in possession of Team
>     A while at or beyond the line to gain
> - Enforcement of a foul by Team B
>     results in the placement of the ball at or beyond the line to gain, or
>     if the enforcement of a foul awards an automatic first down to Team A
> - If there is a change of possession during the down, and Team A has
>     possession at the end of the down
> - The kicking team recovers a
>     scrimmage kick anywhere in the field of play after it first has been
>     touched beyond the line of scrimmage by the receivers.
> - The kicking team legally recovers a free kick.
>
> **ARTICLE 2. NEW SERIES FOR TEAM B**
>
> A new series of four scrimmage downs is awarded to Team B
>   when the following conditions exist:
>
> - Team A fails to advance the ball to the line to gain during a series
>     of downs; or
> - There is a change of possession during the down, and Team
>     B has possession at the end of the down, or has been awarded
>     possession at the end of the down; or
> - When the ball is declared dead
>     in possession of the receiving team after a free kick, scrimmage kick,
>     or fair-catch kick.