# In basketball, what does 'two for fifteen' mean?

Tags: basketball, terminology, scoring

> He was raggedy as... Went two for 15. Seven points.
>   He finished with 16 points on six of 14.

I guess it is about points, but I really don't understand what they mean.
Could someone explain what these phrases mean?

Comment: Note: The [answer posted on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/185412) includes the phrase "1st and 10," which has been [previously addressed here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/15092).

Comment: Not clear.  Could be the same players started poorly and finished a bit better.

Answer (score 5):

> Went two for 15. Seven points.

This specific player made two field goals (FGM - field goals made) out of 15 attempts (FGA - field goals attempted) for a total of seven points (PTS).

> He finished with 16 points on six of 14.

This specific player made six field goals (FGM - field goals made) out of 14 attempts (FGA - field goals attempted) for a total of 16 points (PTS).

Total field goals made/attempts include three point field goals made/attempts. Made free throws (FTM) also contribute to the number of points. These are possible reasons for discrepancies in point totals when reading such phrases.

I was not able to find the specific quote you highlight in your question, so I am attempting to break it down based on my interpretation. It doesn't make sense for a player to go 2 for 15 for 7 points AND 6 for 14 for 16 points without additional context (one player is being talked about across two separate games OR two separate players are being talked about in one game), so I chose the latter context to answer this question.